# How to change accordion css to plain white?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularjs and bootstrap accordion and I need to make the accordion in plain white color without any border or colors. Something like below image.

[image]

My code

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <accordion>
            <accordion-group is-open="item.open" ng-repeat="item in filterGroup | filter:searchText">
                <accordion-heading>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-click="filterHeaderClick(item.title, $event)" ng-model="master" value="{{item.title}}"/>{{ item.title }}
                    <span class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': item.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-up': !item.open}"></span>
                </accordion-heading>
                <div ng-repeat="data in item.content">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-click="filterSubitemClick(data, item.title, $event)" ng-checked="master" value="{{data}}" />{{data}}
                </div>
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="applyFilterClick($event)">Apply Filter</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$scope.filterGroup = [{
    title: "Task Type",
    content: ["Task Type 1", "Task Type 2", "Task Type 3", "Task Type 4"],
    open: false,
    checked: false

}, {
    title: "Connectors",
    content: ["c1", "c2"],
    open: false,
    checked: false
}, {
    title: "Schedules",
    content: ["s1", "s2"],
    open: false,
    checked: false
}, {
    title: "Secure Agents",
    content: ["a1", "zmr"],
    open: false,
    checked: false
}];
```

My accordion screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can't do much without the CSS.

Comment: please provide a fiddle or demo or at least some css associated with it.........

Answer (score 2):

As @Aditya Sethi said you need to override bootstrap css, but there is also a panel-heading image that needs to be removed. Wrap your `panel-body` div inside a below custom div

```
<div id="custom-accord">
    <!-- your panel-body content-->
</div>
```

and below css

```
#custom-accord .panel-default {
    border-color: white !important;
}
#custom-accord .panel-heading {
    background-color: white !important;
    border-color: white !important; 
    background-image: none !important;
}
#custom-accord .panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse .panel-body {
    border-top: 0px white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override css of bootstrap. I would suggest you to use scss and and control this functionality with it.

Your html

```
<div class="custom">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <accordion>
                <accordion-group is-open="item.open" ng-repeat="item in filterGroup | filter:searchText">
                    <accordion-heading>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-click="filterHeaderClick(item.title, $event)" ng-model="master" value="{{item.title}}"/>{{ item.title }}
                        <span class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': item.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-up': !item.open}"></span>
                    </accordion-heading>
                    <div ng-repeat="data in item.content">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-click="filterSubitemClick(data, item.title, $event)" ng-checked="master" value="{{data}}" />{{data}}
                    </div>
                </accordion-group>
            </accordion>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="applyFilterClick($event)">Apply Filter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In your scss file

```
.custom {
    .panel-default>.panel-heading {
        background-color: white !important;
        border-color: white !important;
    }

    .panel-default {
        border-color: white !important;
    }

    .panel-default>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse .panel-body {
        border-color: white !important;
    }
}
```